# Google App Engine error while using Spring and Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, google-app-engine

I am using Spring 2.0 and hibernate, but I am getting following error when I am trying to port my application to GAE.

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: 
        Type 'org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. 
        For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.:
        instance = org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
        Error creating bean with name 'ManagerAdmin' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
        Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory';
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
        Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: 
        Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: 
        Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]:
        Error setting property values; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotWritablePropertyException: 
        Invalid property 'hibernate.dialect' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: 
        Nested property in path 'hibernate.dialect' does not exist; 
    nested exception is org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'hibernate' of bean class [org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource]: 
        Bean property 'hibernate' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: 
        Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter
```

Here is the application.xml that I am using:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
<property name="driverClassName" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://cloudsql/XXXXX:XXXX/XXXXdb?user=XXXX" />
<property name="username" value="XXXXX" />
<property name="password" value="XXXXX" />
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Raja.

After following Ean's, recommendation on correcting applicationContext.xml. I am now getting following error.

```
javax.servlet.ServletContext log: Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call
com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type 'org.hibernate.exception.DataException' was not included in the set of types which can be serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.: instance = org.hibernate.exception.DataException: Cannot open connection
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:665)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:585)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeClass(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:755)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeImpl(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:794)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serialize(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:667)
    at com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.impl.AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.writeObject(AbstractSerializationStreamWriter.java:126)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter$ValueWriter$8.write(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:153)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.impl.ServerSerializationStreamWriter.serializeValue(ServerSerializationStreamWriter.java:585)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponse(RPC.java:605)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.encodeResponseForFailure(RPC.java:393)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RPC.invokeAndEncodeResponse(RPC.java:579)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processCall(RemoteServiceServlet.java:208)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.RemoteServiceServlet.processPost(RemoteServiceServlet.java:248)
    at com.google.gwt.user.server.rpc.AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.doPost(AbstractRemoteServiceServlet.java:62)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:35)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:266)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:76)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:146)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:446)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
    at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
    at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
    at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:251)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: I did my best editing the stack trace but not sure how readable it is. Please make sure you format your question properly and put the full stack-trace as it's been printed on your output log.

Comment: Thanks Ean, for editing and making stack trace readable. I corrected the application.xml file based on your recommendation. Now I am getting another error.. I am going to paste that error below... Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The answer basically solved your initial problem. This is a new and different one saying `Can not open connection`. Check your db URL and network connectivity.

Comment: Yes you are right, it solved the original problem... I used this db url <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://cloudsql/zrfootballsite:cricdb-dev/cricdb?user=root" />
Do you know where can I find the users and password in cloud sql to confirm the id and password.

Comment: Unfortunately not! I have no idea how `google-app-engine` works! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `hibernate.dialect` is a Hibernate property which should be passed to `sessionFactory`. You are passing that to `dataSource` bean which is not aware of such property. Follow is a sample that you should be doing something like that:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.google.appengine.api.rdbms.AppEngineDriver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:google:rdbms://cloudsql/XXXXX:XXXX/XXXXdb?user=XXXX" />
    <property name="username" value="XXXXX" />
    <property name="password" value="XXXXX" />
</bean>

<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.project.EntityClass</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>     
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Notice how `hibernate.dialect` has been passed.